# Sending emails via gmail, Laravel

Tags: laravel, smtp, gmail

can anyone know if there is any difference in sending emails via gmail in Laravel 5.5 on localhost and on global server, because on localhost everything works fine, emails are sent without problem but on global server all the time crashes my authentication error go on configuration connection does not change. Of course, I have enabled mail access for less secure applications. I wonder if it's a problem with mail or a change of environment, from local to global, or something else must change in the .env file configuration or directly in the application. Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Possibly it occurred because of app environment. Try keeping debugging on. And trace back the authentication error. Try sending dummy email with simple text.
And after making changes in env file empty config caches using `php artisan cache:clear`. Many times config doesn't change because of caching.
Good Luck!